# VB2013, Possible Arithmetic Error

Tags: vb.net

In Shadowrun 5e there is a rule concerning explosives in confined spaces called the 'Chunky Salsa Effect'.  I am trying to create a program that simulates the 'Chunky Salsa Effect'.  I have most of the program working, however, as the size of the space [meters] increases, the number of blast reflections [bounces] increases.  It should be the inverse, the blast falloff [minusMeters] should decrease the [bounces].  [walls] determines the number of surfaces the blast reflects off of.  [damageDice] is equal to the base damage of the explosive [baseDamageDice] + (([damageDice]/2) per reflection).  For some reason [damageDice] and [bounces] do not decrease when [meters] is increased.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim meters As Integer = 0
    Dim dice As Integer = 0
    Dim damageDice As Integer = 0
    Dim baseDamageDice As Integer = 0
    Dim bounces As Integer = 0
    Dim hits As Integer = 0
    Dim walls As Integer = 0
    Dim minusMeters As Integer = 0
    Dim explosiveType As Integer = 0
    Dim ap As String = "-"
    Dim diceRoll As Integer = 0

    Randomize()

    walls = CInt(txtWalls.Text)

    explosiveType = cbExplosiveType.SelectedIndex

    If explosiveType < 0 Then
        explosiveType = 0
        cbExplosiveType.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If

    Select Case explosiveType
        Case 0
            minusMeters = 1
            baseDamageDice = 18
            ap = "+5"
        Case 1
            minusMeters = 2
            baseDamageDice = 16
            ap = "-2"
        Case 2
            minusMeters = 4
            baseDamageDice = 24
            ap = "-4"
        Case 3
            minusMeters = 4
            baseDamageDice = 24
            ap = "-10"
        Case 4
            minusMeters = 1
            baseDamageDice = 23
            ap = "+5"
        Case 5
            minusMeters = 2
            baseDamageDice = 21
            ap = "-2"
    End Select

    diceRoll = CInt(Math.Floor((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1

    If diceRoll >= 5 Then
        hits = hits + 1
    End If

    dice = baseDamageDice

    For x = 1 To walls

        meters = CInt(txtMeters.Text)
        damageDice = baseDamageDice

        Do

            damageDice = Math.Round(damageDice / 2)
            dice = dice + damageDice
            meters = meters - minusMeters
            bounces = bounces + 1

        Loop While meters >= 0

    Next

    For i As Integer = 1 To dice
        diceRoll = CInt(Math.Floor((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1

        If diceRoll >= 5 Then
            hits = hits + 1
        End If
    Next

    lblHitsPerBounce.Text = Math.Round(hits / bounces)
    lblTimes.Text = bounces
    lblResult.Text = dice
    lblNumHits.Text = hits
    lblAPOutput.Text = ap

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give some values for the current variables? Also which type they are? Say damageDice is 1, each time the loop goes through Math.Round(damageDice / 2), would be Math.Round(0.5) = 1, so it wouldn't really go down. Could you reformat your question a bit better? Now it looks like a huge hump of text :D Also, bounces is increasing here, no?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and debug it?  `damageDice` need not be recalced in the loop and `dice` is not used.  what is the value of `minusMeters`?  The starting values of some of these things might   not be what you expect.

Comment: I got flagged for putting up too much code on my last try for this question.  I'll edit for a more complete view of the code.

Comment: I've tried breakpoints, my last serious programming activity was developing METCAL applications for test equipment about seven years ago.  (METCAL is a FORTRAN typed language used to control test equipment over a GPIB interface)

Comment: if i get the logic in your description correct, shouldn't the increase of `dice` be outside of the loop? So that you only add the recalculated damageDice, instead of the full sequence of recalculations? I guess, the same would then also go for `bounces`

Comment: put the cursor on the first line, press [F9] or DEBUG -> Toggle Break.  you can execute each line one at a time and examine variable values just by holding the mouse over them. The Locals Window may be helpful too.  Since you have 4 `dice` related variables, there may be cruft messing something up.